# Is this Diophantine equation proof correct?

Tags: diophantine-equations, proof-writing

It's probably a good thing I decided to try working on problems from the book.  This section seems to be proving difficult.  In any case, I'm asked to prove that

$x^4+4y^4=z^2$

has no non-trivial integer solutions.  I want to make sure I have this right.  I start by trying to prove if non-trivial solutions exist, there exist solutions where $x$, $y$, and $z$ are coprime.  My first step is to assume there exists an odd prime $p$ such that $p|z^2$ and $p|x^4$.  Then $p|z$, $p|x$, $p|4y^4$, and $p|y$.  Then $p^4|y^4$, $p^4|x^4$, and $p^4|z^2$.  If $p^4|z^2$, $p^2|z$.  So there exist integers $a$, $b$, and $c$ such that

$x=pa,y=pb,z=p^2c$

$p^4a^4+4p^4b^4=p^4c^2, a^4+4b^4=c^2$.

So I can divide out all odd primes.  Now if $2|x$, $2|z$.  So integers $a$ and $b$ exist such that

$x=2a,z=2b$

$16a^4+4y^4=4b^2, y^4+4a^4=b^2$.

Eventually, $z^2$ will run out of factors of 2, so there must be a solution (if any exist) where $x$ and $z$ are odd.  Therefore, if solutions exist, there must be a solution where $x$, $y$, and $z$ share no common factors.  Then it follows that $(x^2,2y^2,z)$ is a primitive Pythagorean triple.  So there exist $m$ and $n$ such that

$\gcd(m,n)=1,x^2=m^2-n^2,2y^2=2mn,y^2=mn,z=m^2+n^2$

Now since $y^2=mn$ and $\gcd(m,n)=1$, $m$ and $n$ must be square numbers.  So let $m=a^2$ and $n=b^2$.  Then $x^2=a^4-b^4$.  But there's a theorem proven in the book that states this equation has no integer solutions.  Therefore, there are no solutions where $x$, $y$, and $z$ are coprime which in turn means there are no non-trivial solutions.

So again, is this all correct?

Comment: I'm extremely confident that they want you to use
$$ x^4 + 4 y^4 = (x^2 - 2 x y + 2 y^2) (x^2 + 2 x y + 2 y^2).$$

Comment: Looks good. Even though it is pretty obvious, you should probably deal with all combinations of primes dividing two of the variables, not just deal with the variables $x$ and $z$. You have of course pushed the descent argument onto an already proved result, but if it has *already* been proved in detail in the course, that's fine. But it is not fine if quoting the theorem involves looking ahead.

Comment: @Will I would never have seen that and if I had, I'm not sure what I would have done with it from there.  Hmm...  So $z^2=(x^2+2y^2)^2-(2xy)^2$.  Not coming to me.  I figured if there was a theorem from the section it wanted me to use, it would be that the area of a Pythagorean triple is never equal to a square number.  Wait...  Aw crap...  I did all this for nothing.  This right triangle would have area $(xy)^2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Nope, the theorem was from the same section.  And proved using the theorem I mentioned from my last comment.  The theorem I should have used.  The proof given was not at all obvious.  It would have been an easier application to this problem.